# How to select top 30% of cells in a raster (by cell value) in R

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster in R, I need to select the highest cell values up until 30% of the raster area is selected.

The way that I've tried to accomplish this is by calculating the average cell area, and then calculating how many cells I need to meet this 30% target (I know this is not entirely accurate). Then I sort the raster values, descending. Here is where I'm stuck. Of these sorted values, I need to set all cells beyond #12,678 to NA. I can't figure out how to set values to NA based on their place in an order. Does anyone know how to do this? Or have a better idea for the entire process?

Comment: You will likely get faster, better help by providing your data in a reproducible format, something like `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tidyterra` for this.

Once that you have identified your thresold (12,678) use `tidyterra::filter()` on your raster.

I don't know if you are using `raster` or `terra`, I use here `terra` and I show you how to convert back to `Raster*` object.

On this example I present a full workflow with an example raster file, just adapt it to your data.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21
library(tidyterra)
#> -- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyterra 0.1.0 --
#> 
#> Suppress this startup message by setting Sys.setenv(tidyterra.quiet = TRUE)
#> v tibble 3.1.7     v dplyr  1.0.9
#> v tidyr  1.2.0

# Create a SpatRaster from a file
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra")
r <- rast(f)

# If you are using raster package use this line for switch it to terra:
# r <- rast(your_data)

r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : elev.tif 
#> name        : elevation 
#> min value   :       141 
#> max value   :       547

totarea_km <- expanse(r, unit = "km")
prettyNum(totarea_km, big.mark = ",")
#> [1] "2,563.61"

plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
# There is a bug on slice_max, use filter

# Get thresold for filtering by working on the values of the raster
# as it is a data frame
min_value <- as_tibble(r, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = elevation, prop = .3) %>%
  min()

# Here it goes!!
top30perc <- r %>% filter(elevation > min_value)

# Check
area_30perc <- expanse(top30perc, unit = "km")

prettyNum(area_30perc, big.mark = ",")
#> [1] "761.0991"

# Check
area_30perc / totarea_km
#> [1] 0.2968857

# Seems ok


plot(top30perc)
```

[image]

```r
# If you need to convert to Raster* object

raster::stack(top30perc)
#> class      : RasterStack 
#> dimensions : 90, 95, 8550, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> names      : elevation 
#> min values :       387 
#> max values :       547
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: A better alternative would be `slice_max()` but I found a bug, now reported: https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

If you assume a constant cell size, then you might as well ignore it and you can do something like this (find the quantile of interest and use that as a threshold):

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra"))

q <- global(r, \(i) quantile(i, 0.7, na.rm=T))
x <- ifel(r <= q[[1]], NA, r)
plot(x)
```

Check

```
g <- global(c(x,r), "notNA")
g[1,1]/g[2,1]
# 0.2979601
```

If variation in cell size is important, you could do something like the below (sort the values, and find the cells below the cumulative cell size threshold), but note that this approach is not memory-safe (would fail with very large rasters)

```
s <- c(r, cellSize(r, unit="km"))
d <- as.data.frame(s, cell=T, na.rm=T)
d <- d[order(d$elevation, decreasing=TRUE), ]
d$sumarea <- cumsum(d$area) / sum(d$area)
cells <- d[d$sumarea <= 0.3, "cell"]
msk <- rast(r)
msk[cells] <- 1
x <- mask(r, msk)
plot(x)
```